# Why entropy is undefined in low contrast image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, c++

I am trying to measure contrast of image by entropy of histogram of image.

Code for computing entropy

```
float measureContrast_inImage(Mat imagel) {

    Mat hist;
    /// Establish the number of bins
    int histSize = 256;
    /// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
    float range[] = { 0, 256 };
    const float* histRange = { range };
    bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;
    /// Compute the histograms:
    calcHist(&imagel, 1, 0, Mat(), hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);
    hist /= imagel.total();

    Mat logP;
    cv::log(hist, logP);

    cv::imshow("logP", logP);

    //Performs an element-wise multiplication or division of the two matrices
    float entropy = -1 * sum(hist.mul(logP)).val[0];

    cout << entropy << endl;

    //float entropy = 0;

    waitKey(0);
    return entropy;
}
```

Lena image
[image]

**But entropy is -nan(ind)**

similarly, entropy is undefined for another Image.

[image]

Entropy is 5.29657 for another image. 
[image]

Is there any problem in my code.

I wonder that why in low contrast image, entropy is undefined. Kindly help me to figure out.

**Edited**

I computed histogram and get entropy by the following code 
and my entropy is 256

```
float entropy(Mat seq, Size size, int index)
{

    int cnt = 0;

    float entr = 0;

    float total_size = size.height * size.width; //total size of all symbols in an image

    for (int i = 0; i<index; i++)
    {

        float sym_occur = (float)seq.at<uchar>(0, i); //the number of times a sybmol has occured

        if (sym_occur>0) //log of zero goes to infinity

        {

            cnt++;

            entr += (sym_occur / total_size)*(log2(total_size / sym_occur));

        }
    }

    cout << "cnt: " << cnt << endl;

    return entr;
}

void imhist(Mat image, int histogram[])
{
    // initialize all intensity values to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        histogram[i] = 0;
    }

    // calculate the no of pixels for each intensity values
    for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)
            histogram[(int)image.at<uchar>(y, x)]++;
}

Mat histDisplay(int histogram[], const char* name)
{
    int hist[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        hist[i] = histogram[i];
    }
    // draw the histograms
    int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;
    int bin_w = cvRound((double)hist_w / 256);

    Mat histImage(hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    // find the maximum intensity element from histogram
    int max = hist[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        if (max < hist[i]) {
            max = hist[i];
        }
    }

    // normalize the histogram between 0 and histImage.rows

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        hist[i] = ((double)hist[i] / max)*histImage.rows;
    }


    // draw the intensity line for histogram
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        /*line(histImage, cvPoint(bin_w*(i), hist_h),
        cvPoint(bin_w*(i), hist_h - hist[i]),
        Scalar(0, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);*/
        line(histImage, cvPoint(bin_w*(i), hist_h),
            cvPoint(bin_w*(i), hist_h - hist[i]),
            Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    }

    // display histogram
    //namedWindow(name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    //imshow(name, histImage);
    return histImage;
}

int main () {
    Mat image = imread("lena.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    int hist[256];
    imhist(image, hist);
    Mat histImg = histDisplay(hist, "hist");

    float en = entropy(histImg, image.size(), 256);
}
```

I believe that it is still wrong. 
Please correct me .

Comment: You can put your code in a **try-catch** block and then you'll be able to catch the line that is causing the exception (just put a breakpoint somewhere in your catch block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a nan returned because you are performing an operation that yields undefined result.

Based on your code, the only option I can see is the log operater that theoretically yields $-\infty$ when you attempt to take the logarithm of a 0-valued pixel. C++ will thus consider it not a number. Other functions I have seen for calculating entropy such as [this example in octave](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/entropy.html), just ignore the zero pixels to solve these cases.

Comment: so you mean iterate every intensity frequency and check if it is > 0,

Comment: Correct, but since you shouldn't have to expect negative values I would just check for intensity values not equal to zero and throw exception if the are bellow. thus, you won't miss innapropriate images for the method.

Comment: i tried it. but there is another problem i got .How can i share it? Should i edit my question? or i should post another question ?

Comment: Also, cam i use histogram in int values?

Comment: Please check me edited question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will not go through all of your code and check what could be wrong. I will however, suggest to start by printing your variables "entr" and "sym_occur" in every itteration and backtrack where you find an error.

Comment: ok i corrected it. but still dark image and less low contrast image has same entropy. which should not be. i think this method is not good for determining image contrast.